# Cassandra loses column values during cross datacenter replication

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax-enterprise

We have two Cassandra datacenters. Data propagated from the first DC to the second. Sometimes we observe corrupted records in the second DC. It looks like this: partition and clustering columns are presented, but all other columns are null. We have started to observe it right after upgrade to DSE 6.8.25. Does anybody meet this issue?

This issue can be solved by Reaper run. But we want to understand a root cause. Why it happens. And how it could be fixed.